# Convert old Oracle outer join syntax (+) to JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle10g, ms-access-2010

I have a query that was written for Oracle using the old `(+)` syntax and  now I want to convert it to Access SQL.

Here is my query:

```
select BOOKCODE.BOOKCODEID,BOOKCODE.BOOKCODENAME 
from Application_bookcode, BookCode 
where BOOKCODE.BOOKCODEID (+) = HMISUnitTest.APPLICATION_BOOKCODE.BOOKCODEID 
  and HMISUnitTest.APPLICATION_BOOKCODE.ApplicationId = 7
```

What is the equivalent in Access SQL?

Comment: what does `(+) = ` mean in oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember the old Oracle outer join syntax (and it's been a *long time*), the corresponding query in Access should be

```sql
SELECT 
    BOOKCODE.BOOKCODEID,
    BOOKCODE.BOOKCODENAME 
FROM 
    Application_bookcode
    LEFT JOIN
    BookCode 
        ON BOOKCODE.BOOKCODEID = APPLICATION_BOOKCODE.BOOKCODEID 
WHERE
    APPLICATION_BOOKCODE.ApplicationId = 7
```