# Trying to migrate from Oracle to PostgreSQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql

```
SELECT b.SERVICENAME,
       a.PARAMETERNAME,
       a.PARAMETERVALUE
FROM serviceParameter a,
     subscriberService b,
     serviceName c
WHERE a.SUBSCRIBERKEY (+) = 15677889
  AND b.SUBSCRIBERKEY = 15677889
  AND b.SERVICENAME = a.SERVICENAME(+)
  AND c.SERVICENAME = b.SERVICENAME
  AND c.MULTIINSTANCE = '0'
ORDER BY a.SERVICENAME;
```

How can I migrate the above code to PostgresSQL?

Comment: Aside from learning how to write Left and Right Outer Joins, what issues are you running into. This might be a good start: https://www.dofactory.com/sql/left-outer-join

Comment: I have tried by changing like below

Comment: SELECT b.SERVICENAME,a.PARAMETERNAME ,a.PARAMETERVALUE  FROM serviceparameter a right outer join subscriberservice b ON
  b.serviceName  = a.
    SERVICENAME  inner join  servicename c ON 
    c.SERVICENAME  = b.
    SERVICENAME   WHERE 
    a.SUBSCRIBERKEY (+) = $1 AND 
    b.SUBSCRIBERKEY  = $2 AND 
    c.MULTIINSTANCE  = '0'
     ORDER BY a."SERVICENAME;

Comment: getting an error as

Comment: syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: ...rviceName = b.ServiceName  WHERE a.SubscriberKey(+) = $1 AND.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert old Oracle outer join syntax (+) to JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825228/convert-old-oracle-outer-join-syntax-to-join)

Comment: @rashmi Why are you attempting to do a left outer join (a.SUBSCRIBERKEY) to a constant value? I think that can be removed from the query

Comment: @bogertron i am trying to migrate from existing oracle query to postgresql

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the version of postgresql is 11

Answer (score 0):

You have to translate it along these lines:

```
SELECT ...
FROM a, b
WHERE a.x = b.y(+)
  AND a.p = 42
  AND b.q(+) = 'foo';
```

will become:

```
SELECT ...
FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b
        ON a.x = b.y
           AND b.q = 'foo'
WHERE a.p = 42;
```

That is:

- The side with the `(+)` becomes the right side of a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (or, equivalently, the left side of a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`).
- All the `WHERE` conditions that contain a `(+)` lose that adornment and go into the *join condition*.

It is easy to translate Oracle's join syntax to standard conforming syntax because the latter is more powerful (and easier to read to boot).

Comment: As per my above example should i do inner join with the c table?

Comment: It is an outer join of `a` and `b`, but an inner join of `b` and `c`. So something like `b JOIN c LEFT JOIN a`.